# Simultaneous AVCaptureVideoDataOutput and AVCaptureMovieFileOutput

Tags: iphone, ios, camera, video-capture, record

I need to be able to have `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` and `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` working at the same time. The below code works, however, the video recording does not. The `didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL` delegate is called directly after `startRecordingToOutputFileURL` is called. Now if i remove `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` from the 
`AVCaptureSession` by simply commenting out the line:

`[captureSession addOutput:captureDataOutput];`

The video recording works but then the SampleBufferDelegate is not called (which i need).

How can i go about having `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` and `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` working simultaneously.

```
- (void)initCapture {
 AVCaptureDeviceInput *captureInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:[AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] error:NULL]; 

 captureDataOutput = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init]; 
 [captureDataOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()]; 

 m_captureFileOutput = [[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput alloc] init];

 NSString* key = (NSString*)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey; 
 NSNumber* value = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA]; 
 NSDictionary* videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:value forKey:key]; 

 [captureDataOutput setVideoSettings:videoSettings]; 

 captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init]; 

 [captureSession addInput:captureInput];
 [captureSession addOutput:m_captureFileOutput]; 
 [captureSession addOutput:captureDataOutput]; 

 [captureSession beginConfiguration]; 
 [captureSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetLow]; 
 [captureSession commitConfiguration]; 

 [self performSelector:@selector(startRecording) withObject:nil afterDelay:10.0];
 [self performSelector:@selector(stopRecording) withObject:nil afterDelay:15.0];

 [captureSession startRunning];
}


- (void) startRecording
{
    [m_captureFileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:[self tempFileURL] recordingDelegate:self];

}

- (void) stopRecording
{
    if([m_captureFileOutput isRecording])
 [m_captureFileOutput stopRecording];

}


- (NSURL *) tempFileURL
{
 NSString *outputPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%@", NSTemporaryDirectory(), @"camera.mov"];
 NSURL *outputURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:outputPath];
 NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
 if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:outputPath]) {
  [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:outputPath error:nil];
 [outputPath release];
 return [outputURL autorelease];
}



- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)captureOutput didStartRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)fileURL fromConnections:(NSArray *)connections
{
 NSLog(@"start record video");
}

- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)captureOutput didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)outputFileURL fromConnections:(NSArray *)connections error:(NSError *)error
{
 NSLog(@"end record");
}


- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection 
{ 
      // do stuff with sampleBuffer
}
```

I should add i am getting the error:

```
Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12780 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -12780.)" UserInfo=0x23fcd0 {AVErrorRecordingSuccessfullyFinishedKey=false}
```

from

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)captureOutput didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)outputFileURL fromConnections:(NSArray *)connections error:(NSError *)error
```

Cheers

Comment: There is a proven working way to do this. More in this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944083/can-use-avcapturevideodataoutput-and-avcapturemoviefileoutput-at-the-same-time

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I have contacted an engineer at Apple's support and he told me that simultaneous `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` + `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` use is not supported. I don't know if they will support it in the future, but he used the word "not supported at this time".

I encourage you to fill a bug report / feature request on this, as I did (bugreport.apple.com), as they measure how hard people want something and we perhaps can see this in a near future.

Comment: Be sure to see Oded's comment above with a working solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944083/can-use-avcapturevideodataoutput-and-avcapturemoviefileoutput-at-the-same-time

Comment: @StanJames is it still the case today where oded's workaround is the best approach to using AVCaptureVideoDataOutput + AVCaptureMovieFileOutput simultaneously?

Comment: @StanJames if the goal is to create two videos simultaneously could you use two AVAssetWriters (with only AVCaptureVideoDataOutput) instead of both AVCaptureVideoDataOutput and AVCaptureMovieFileOutput?

Comment: Does anyone have an updates on whether this is still impossible or not?

Comment: @SpaceDog Could you provide a proof of this?

Comment: @SashaKid - This was 6 years ago. At the time I have opened a paid technical incident to ask that and this was what they answered me, but like I said, that was 6 years ago. Perhaps it is possible to do that today, I don't know.

Comment: @SpaceDog I see that it's still not possible to have both AVCaptureVideoDataOutput + AVCaptureMovieFileOutput. My delegate method AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate not called :-(

Comment: To be honest, that's kind of ridiculous. There are so many situations where you'd need both and 7 years later it's still not possible.

Comment: Apple never fixes anything that is important, unless it blows on them by the press. They fix what commercially makes sense for them. I have bugs there since 2008 that were never fixed and will ever be fixed.

Comment: 03.2020 still nothing T_T

Answer (score 4):

Still 9 years later Apple apparently does not seem to want this to work together.

But you can easily work with AVAssetWriter.

> You can't use AVCaptureVideoDataOutput and AVCaptureMovieFileOutput on the same time. But  you can use AVCaptureVideoDataOutput and analyse or modify on the data, then use AVAsseWriter to write the frames to a file.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/98113

How to save video with output using AVAssetWriter:

[Save AVCaptureVideoDataOutput to movie file using AVAssetWriter in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51209310/save-avcapturevideodataoutput-to-movie-file-using-avassetwriter-in-swift)

Answer (score 3):

Although you cannot use `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`, you *can* use `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` simultaneously with `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput`. See the "AVCam" example on Apple's Website.

In Xamarin.iOS, the code looks like this:

```
var session = new AVCaptureSession();

var camera = AVCaptureDevice.DefaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaType.Video);
var  mic = AVCaptureDevice.DefaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaType.Audio);
if(camera == null || mic == null){
    throw new Exception("Can't find devices");
}

if(session.CanAddInput(camera)){
    session.AddInput(camera);
}
if(session.CanAddInput(mic)){
   session.AddInput(mic);
}

var layer = new AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session);
layer.LayerVideoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.ResizeAspectFill;
layer.VideoGravity = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.GravityResizeAspectFill;

cameraView = new UIView();
cameraView.Layer.AddSublayer(layer);

var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine( Path.GetTempPath(), "temporary.mov");
var fileUrl = NSUrl.FromFilename( filePath );

var movieFileOutput = new AVCaptureMovieFileOutput();
var recordingDelegate = new MyRecordingDelegate();
session.AddOutput(movieFileOutput);

movieFileOutput.StartRecordingToOutputFile( fileUrl, recordingDelegate);
```

Answer (score -1):

XCode 14.1 is already support it.

- XCode 13.4: Not works
- XCode 14.1: works

Comment: This is not true. I upgraded my XCode to 14.1 today and still, as soon as you add `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` to the capture session, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate stops receiving sample buffers.

Comment: It still works on XCode 14.1 my side. Please try to move AVCaptureMovieFileOutput to before AVCaptureMovieDataOutput and try again.

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work, can't get any sample buffers.

Comment: @Ashkan Sarlak Step1: comment out AVCaptureMovieFileOutput then  AVCaptureMovieDataOutput works?. Step2: comment out AVCaptureMovieDataOutput then AVCaptureMovieFileOutput works?. Please make sure you did add delegate function for captureOutput.

Comment: 1. yes. 2. yes and yes everything is in place. Actually I just did it using `AVAssetWriter` trick and right now don't care about this approach anymore. Thank you for this discussion.

Comment: Of course AVAssetWriter alway works. But I don't know why AVCaptureMovieFileOutput and AVCaptureMovieDataOutput not worked your side. If you are using AVAssetWriter with audio, please take care blank frames at first and last video because sometime Audio Buffer coming first and last.

Comment: That was a good advice, seems like audio buffer comes first and there'll be some blank frames at the start, thanks.