# Convert Landscape Video to Portrait Video

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, swift4

How to ***Convert Landscape Video in to Portrait Video*** and Save in Swift?

I am Work in Video Editor app. but i don't know how to convert video orientation in swift.

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik i don't know how to do this.

Comment: see this for help : https://medium.com/@sunnyleeyun/swift-100-days-project-24-portrait-landscape-how-to-allow-rotate-in-one-vc-d717678301c1

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik i am trying to rotate only video not a ViewController.

Comment: then change the frame of your view  based on the orientation

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72090169/4833705

Answer (score -1):

First get video orientation using following code:

```
func getVideoOrientationFromAsset(asset: AVAsset) -> UIImageOrientation {
    let videoTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: .video)[0]
    let size = videoTrack.naturalSize

    guard let txf = asset.tracks(withMediaType: .video).first?.preferredTransform else {
        return .up
    }

    if (size.width == txf.tx && size.height == txf.ty) {
        return .left
    }
    else if (txf.tx == 0 && txf.ty == 0) {
        return .right
    }
    else if (txf.tx == 0 && txf.ty == size.width) {
        return .down
    }
    else {
        return .up
    }
}
```

Then apply Translation and Rotation based on orientation with AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction and AVMutableVideoComposition on video for rendering proper output.

Comment: @chetanoptimumbrew
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26932794/square-cropping-and-fixing-the-video-orientation-in-ios?lq=1