# CGAffineTransform -How to Align Video in Screen Center

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, cgaffinetransform, avvideocomposition

I've been able to center the middle of a 16:9 landscape video, crop the video, and then create a 9:16 portrait version of the video similar to how Apple [does it](https://www.idownloadblog.com/2019/07/15/crop-video-ios-13/) in the Photos album.

[image]

The only issue is the resulting portrait video isn't centered in the middle of the screen (images below).

How can I get the resulting portrait video in the center of the screen?

```
func createExportSession(for videoURL: URL) {

    let asset = AVURLAsset(url: videoURL)
    let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: asset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)!

    exporter.videoComposition = turnHorizontalVideoToPortraitVideo(asset: asset)

    exporter.outputURL = // ...
    exporter.outputFileType = AVFileType.mp4
    exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true

    exporter.exportAsynchronously { [weak self] in

        // ...

        // the exporter.url is eventually added to an AVURLAsset and played inside an AVPlayer
    }
}

func turnHorizontalVideoToPortraitVideo(asset: AVURLAsset) -> AVVideoComposition {

    let track = asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video)[0]

    let renderSize = CGSize(width: 720, height: 1280)

    var transform1 = track.preferredTransform
    transform1 = transform1.concatenating(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(90.0 * .pi / 180)))
    transform1 = transform1.concatenating(CGAffineTransform(translationX: track.naturalSize.width, y: 0))

    let transform2 = CGAffineTransform(translationX: track.naturalSize.height, y: (track.naturalSize.width - track.naturalSize.height) / 2)

    let transform3 = transform2.rotated(by: CGFloat(Double.pi/2)).concatenating(transform1)

    let translate = CGAffineTransform(translationX: renderSize.width, y: renderSize.height)
    let rotateFromUpsideDown = translate.rotated(by: CGFloat(Double.pi)) // without this the portrait video is always upside down 

    let finalTransform = transform3.concatenating(rotateFromUpsideDown)

    let transformer = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: track)
    transformer.setTransform(finalTransform, at: .zero)

    let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
    instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRange(start: .zero, duration: asset.duration)
    instruction.layerInstructions = [transformer]

    let videoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
    videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTime(value: 1, timescale: 30)
    videoComposition.renderSize = renderSize
    videoComposition.instructions = [instruction]
        
    return videoComposition
}
```

The initial horizontal video:

[image]

The resulting portrait video after the above code is ran. The video is incorrectly centered on the screen:

[image]

This is the way that it should be centered:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**If anyone has a better answer, please post it, I'll check and accept it**.

Unbeknownst to me the video was in the correct position but the negative black bar space was causing the video to be appear that it was misaligned. Changing the `AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()` `.backgroundColor` shows the negative black bar space issue in **yellow**:

```
instruction.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
```

[image]

To fix it for a `.landscapeRight` video, I divided the `finalTransform.ty` in half and subtracted that from a translation-y-value. For a `.landscapeLeft` video I added the code below:

```
func turnHorizontalVideoToPortraitVideo(asset: AVURLAsset) -> AVVideoComposition {

    let track = asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video)[0]

    let renderSize = CGSize(width: 720, height: 1280)

    let t = track.preferredTransform

    if (t.a == 1.0 && t.b == 0 && t.c == 0 && t.d == 1.0) {
        print("landscapeRight")
    }

    var isLandscapeLeft = false
    if (t.a == -1.0 && t.b == 0 && t.c == 0 && t.d == -1.0) {
        print("landscapeLeft")
        isLandscapeLeft = true
    }

    var transform1 = t
    transform1 = transform1.concatenating(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(90.0 * .pi / 180)))
    transform1 = transform1.concatenating(CGAffineTransform(translationX: track.naturalSize.width, y: 0))

    let transform2 = CGAffineTransform(translationX: track.naturalSize.height, y: (track.naturalSize.width - track.naturalSize.height) / 2)

    var p = Double.pi/2
    if isLandscapeLeft {
        p = -Double.pi/2
    }
    let transform3 = transform2.rotated(by: CGFloat(p)).concatenating(transform1)

    let finalTransform = transform3

    let transformer = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: track)

    if isLandscapeLeft {
            
        let ty = finalTransform.ty
        let dividedNum = ty/2.5
            
        let translation = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: dividedNum)
        let new_finalTransform = finalTransform.concatenating(translation)
            
        transformer.setTransform(new_finalTransform, at: .zero)
    }

    if !isLandscapeLeft {
            
        let translate = CGAffineTransform(translationX: renderSize.width, y: renderSize.height)
        let rotateFromUpsideDown = translate.rotated(by: CGFloat(Double.pi))
        let transformRotated = finalTransform.concatenating(rotateFromUpsideDown)
            
        let ty = transformRotated.ty
            
        var dividedNum = ty/2
            
        if dividedNum < 0 {
            dividedNum = 0
        }
            
        let translation = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -dividedNum)
        let new_finalTransform = transformRotated.concatenating(translation)
            
        transformer.setTransform(new_finalTransform, at: .zero)
    }

    let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
    //instruction.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
    instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRange(start: .zero, duration: asset.duration)
    instruction.layerInstructions = [transformer]
        
    let videoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
    videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTime(value: 1, timescale: 30)
    videoComposition.renderSize = renderSize
    videoComposition.instructions = [instruction]
        
    return videoComposition
}
```

The result for a `.landscapeRight` video:

[image]

The result for a `.landscapeRight` video with the negative black bar space in yellow to show how it's now centered:

[image]