# getting unexpected result of crop video using AVFoundation

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, avfoundation, crop

I have video of 1920*1080(16:9) and I want to crop that video by middle pixel of 1080*1080(1:1).

For that I wrote below code.

```
-(void)cropVideo
{
    AVMutableComposition *mixComposition = [[AVMutableComposition alloc] init];
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *track = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *track1 = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/staticVideo.mp4", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];
    AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];

    [track insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, asset.duration) ofTrack:[[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:CMTimeMake(0, 1) error:nil];
    [track1 insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, asset.duration) ofTrack:[[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:CMTimeMake(0, 1) error:nil];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *myPathDocs =  [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                             [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@1x1.mov",NSBundle.mainBundle.infoDictionary[@"CFBundleExecutable"]]];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:myPathDocs error:nil];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:myPathDocs];

    /** code for crop video*/

    AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction *instruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
    instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, asset.duration);

    AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *layerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:track];

    [layerInstruction setCropRectangle:CGRectMake(420, 0, 1080, 1080) atTime:kCMTimeZero];

    [layerInstruction setOpacity:0.0 atTime:asset.duration];

    instruction.layerInstructions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:layerInstruction,nil];

    AVMutableVideoComposition *mainCompositionInst = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];

    mainCompositionInst.renderSize = CGSizeMake(1080, 1080);
    mainCompositionInst.instructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:instruction];
    mainCompositionInst.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30);

    /** code for crop video*/

    AVAssetExportSession *exporter;
    int currentSize = (int) [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"VideoSize"];
    if (currentSize == 1)
    {
        exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPreset640x480];
    }
    else if (currentSize == 2)
    {
        exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPreset1280x720];
    }
    else if (currentSize == 3)
    {
        exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPreset1920x1080];
    }
    else if (currentSize == 4)
    {
        exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPreset3840x2160];
    }
    exporter.videoComposition = mainCompositionInst;
    exporter.outputURL=url;
    exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
    exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;

    [exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            /*update Video*/
        });
    }];

}
```

Sorry, I can't explain how I want and how I'm getting.

So I'm drew diagram from this you can understand my problem.

[image: diagram]

Like this diagram I want 1080*1080 of A result but I'm getting 1080*1080 of B result.
Here is the screenshot how result B is appearing.
[image: ScreenShot of B result]

Please help me to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This link may helpful to you [How do I use AVFoundation to crop a video](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198245/how-do-i-use-avfoundation-to-crop-a-video)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just decrease value of x for video.

```
CGAffineTransform t1 = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-420, 0);
[layerInstruction setTransform:t1 atTime:kCMTimeZero];
```

And solved my problem...