# How to change aspect ratio of photos taken using AVFoundation?

Tags: objective-c, camera, uiimage, avfoundation, aspect-ratio

I am using AVFoundation to take pictures instead of UIImagePicker due to how customizable the user interface presented to the user can be. When using it the aspect ratio that the picture is saved as is the same as the iPhone's video feed. What I want to happen is to have the pictures saved in the same aspect ratio as normal pictures are.

The way that I am currently approaching this is to overlay a black bar in the excess preview display and then just crop the photo after saving it as an image.

However, this feels very crude. I assume that it is a common thing to use the AVFoundation as a way of taking photos and so I assume I must be missing something!

I have used [this example code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010112). And I have read through the AVFoundation documentation but can only assume that I am missing a function. I have also read through [similar questions to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198245/how-do-i-use-avfoundation-to-crop-a-video?noredirect=1&lq=1) which describe the process by which I might go about cropping images, but that isn't really my concern.

On the other hand, if there is no standard way to do this, please do let me know so that I can stop worrying that I am approaching it in a convoluted way.

Also, I am using Objective-C so if answers contain code, please could you use the same language?

Comment: Have you looked at `AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect`?

Comment: I have, but when I call it on my session using
self.previewView.bounds = AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect(aspectRatio, oldBounds); 
where previewView is the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer

the bounds are not changed. Is this normal behaviour? @JaredH