# Can I have AVCaptureVideoDataOutput and AVCaptureMovieFileOutput in the same session?

Tags: objective-c, ios, avfoundation

I'm developing an app in iOS. I need to capture video from the camera and I need to record that video to a file and also get the uncompressed frames, that's why I need to use both AVCaptureOutput...

I read this in the apple's documentation "You can configure multiple inputs and outputs, coordinated by a single session:" So I think it must be doable, but I'm having problems with it...

I'm setting both to the session doing:

```
self.fileOutput.maxRecordedDuration =  CMTimeMake(5000,1 );;
self.fileOutput.minFreeDiskSpaceLimit = 3000;


if([self.captureSession canAddOutput:self.fileOutput]){
    [self.captureSession addOutput:self.fileOutput];
    NSLog(@"Added File Video Output");
}else{
    NSLog(@"Couldn't add video output");
}

if ([self.captureSession canAddOutput:videoOutput]){
    [self.captureSession addOutput:videoOutput];
    NSLog(@"Added Data Video Output");
}else{
    NSLog(@"Couldn't add video output");
}
```

I'm getting both 'positive' confirmation messages. After that I'm calling to:

```
NSString *assetPath         = [self createAssetFilePath:@"mov"];
NSURL *outputURL            = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:assetPath];
[self.fileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:outputURL recordingDelegate:self];
[self.captureSession startRunning];
```

And then I have my delegate function:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)captureOutput didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)outputFileURL fromConnections:(NSArray *)connections error:(NSError *)error {

NSLog(@"Output File URL: %@ ", outputFileURL);

BOOL recordedSuccessfully = YES;

    if ([error code] != noErr) {

        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        id value = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:AVErrorRecordingSuccessfullyFinishedKey];
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", value);
        if (value) {
            recordedSuccessfully = [value boolValue];
        }

    }
}
```

And I'm getting no error, but the "AVCaptureVideoDataOutput" was working before adding the "AVCaptureMovieFileOutput" and now it's not...

So... Is that possible to do both?! Any idea?!

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to this question: [Simultaneous AVCaptureVideoDataOutput and AVCaptureMovieFileOutput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968879/simultaneous-avcapturevideodataoutput-and-avcapturemoviefileoutput) indicates that you cannot have an AVCaptureVideoDataOutput and a AVCaptureMovieFileOutput to your session simultaneously. I can't verify this in the Apple documentation unfortunately. My experience is that I no longer receive messages to my AVCaptureVideoDataOutput's sampleBufferDelegate after I add an AVCaptureMovieFileOutput to the session's output, which seemingly backs up that assertion.