# AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate not calling its delegate methods ios

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I am using AVFoundation to capture a video and present it on iPhone screen.
I want to know every time a video frame is dropped and get its time, 
I read that this delegate method is exactly what I want:

```
-(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput*)captureOutput didDropSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection*)connection;
```

This is my code setting the delegate:

```
@interface PRVideoRecorderManger ()<AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate>


    AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *videoCaptureOutput = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("myQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
[videoCaptureOutput setAlwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames:YES];
[videoCaptureOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:queue];

// Specify the pixel format
videoCaptureOutput.videoSettings =
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:
 [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA]
                            forKey:(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey]; //kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey


// If you wish to cap the frame rate to a known value, such as 15 fps, set
// minFrameDuration.
videoCaptureOutput.minFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, videoFPS);

if([_captureSession canAddOutput:videoCaptureOutput])
{
    [_captureSession addOutput:videoCaptureOutput];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"can't Add output");
}

_movieFileOutput = [[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput alloc] init];
[[_movieFileOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo ] setVideoOrientation:orientation];
[_captureSession addOutput:_movieFileOutput];
[_movieFileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:outputURL recordingDelegate:self];
[_captureSession startRunning];
```

But captureOutPut:didDropSampleBuffer is NEVER called, why is that?

EDIT:
I  have realised that if i comment AVCaptureMovieFileOutput it does call

```
-(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
```

Is there a way to receive output sample buffer AND finish recording to output file at URL 
because right now it only let me recieve one.

Comment: Word on the street is that you _cannot_ use `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` and `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` together: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4986032/22147

Comment: OH NO, than how can i get the number of frames and time for each frame in the movie?

Comment: You could use only `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` and write the movie using an `AVAssetWriter`.