# Simulate AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill: crop and center video to mimic preview without losing sharpness

Tags: ios, video, avfoundation, avassetwriter, avassetexportsession

Based on this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21077240/cropping-avasset-video-with-avfoundation), the code below rotates, centers, and crops a video captured live by the user.

The capture session uses AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh for the preset value, and the preview layer uses AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill for video gravity. This preview is extremely sharp.

The exported video, however, is not as sharp, ostensibly because scaling from the 1920x1080 resolution for the back camera on the 5S to 320x568 (target size for the exported video) introduces fuzziness from throwing away pixels?

Assuming there is no way to scale from 1920x1080 to 320x568 without some fuzziness, the question becomes: how to mimic the sharpness of the preview layer?

Somehow Apple is using an algorithm to convert a 1920x1080 video into a crisp-looking preview frame of 320x568.

Is there a way to mimic this with either AVAssetWriter or AVAssetExportSession?

```
func cropVideo() {
    // Set start time
    let startTime = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970

    // Create main composition & its tracks
    let mainComposition = AVMutableComposition()
    let compositionVideoTrack = mainComposition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
    let compositionAudioTrack = mainComposition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))

    // Get source video & audio tracks
    let videoPath = getFilePath(curSlice!.getCaptureURL())
    let videoURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: videoPath)
    let videoAsset = AVURLAsset(URL: videoURL, options: nil)
    let sourceVideoTrack = videoAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0]
    let sourceAudioTrack = videoAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio)[0]
    let videoSize = sourceVideoTrack.naturalSize

    // Get rounded time for video
    let roundedDur = floor(curSlice!.getDur() * 100) / 100
    let videoDur = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(roundedDur, 100)

    // Add source tracks to composition
    do {
        try compositionVideoTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoDur), ofTrack: sourceVideoTrack, atTime: kCMTimeZero)
        try compositionAudioTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoDur), ofTrack: sourceAudioTrack, atTime: kCMTimeZero)
    } catch {
        print("Error with insertTimeRange while exporting video: \(error)")
    }

    // Create video composition
    // -- Set video frame
    let outputSize = view.bounds.size
    let videoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
    print("Video composition duration: \(CMTimeGetSeconds(mainComposition.duration))")

    // -- Set parent layer
    let parentLayer = CALayer()
    parentLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, outputSize.width, outputSize.height)
    parentLayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityResizeAspectFill

    // -- Set composition props
    videoComposition.renderSize = CGSize(width: outputSize.width, height: outputSize.height)
    videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, Int32(frameRate))

    // -- Create video composition instruction
    let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
    instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoDur)

    // -- Use layer instruction to match video to output size, mimicking AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
    let videoLayerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: compositionVideoTrack)
    let videoTransform = getResizeAspectFillTransform(videoSize, outputSize: outputSize)
    videoLayerInstruction.setTransform(videoTransform, atTime: kCMTimeZero)

    // -- Add layer instruction
    instruction.layerInstructions = [videoLayerInstruction]
    videoComposition.instructions = [instruction]

    // -- Create video layer
    let videoLayer = CALayer()
    videoLayer.frame = parentLayer.frame

    // -- Add sublayers to parent layer
    parentLayer.addSublayer(videoLayer)

    // -- Set animation tool
    videoComposition.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAsVideoLayer: videoLayer, inLayer: parentLayer)

    // Create exporter
    let outputURL = getFilePath(getUniqueFilename(gMP4File))
    let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mainComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)!
    exporter.outputURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: outputURL)
    exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4
    exporter.videoComposition = videoComposition
    exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
    exporter.canPerformMultiplePassesOverSourceMediaData = true

    // Export to video
    exporter.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler({
        // Log status
        let asset = AVAsset(URL: exporter.outputURL!)
        print("Exported slice video. Tracks: \(asset.tracks.count). Duration: \(CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration)). Size: \(exporter.estimatedOutputFileLength). Status: \(getExportStatus(exporter)). Output URL: \(exporter.outputURL!). Export time: \( NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 - startTime).")

        // Tell delegate
        //delegate.didEndExport(exporter)
        self.curSlice!.setOutputURL(exporter.outputURL!.lastPathComponent!)
        gUser.save()
    })
}


// Returns transform, mimicking AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill, that converts video of <inputSize> to one of <outputSize>
private func getResizeAspectFillTransform(videoSize: CGSize, outputSize: CGSize) -> CGAffineTransform {
    // Compute ratios between video & output sizes
    let widthRatio = outputSize.width / videoSize.width
    let heightRatio = outputSize.height / videoSize.height

    // Set scale to larger of two ratios since goal is to fill output bounds
    let scale = widthRatio >= heightRatio ? widthRatio : heightRatio

    // Compute video size after scaling
    let newWidth = videoSize.width * scale
    let newHeight = videoSize.height * scale

    // Compute translation required to center image after scaling
    // -- Assumes CoreAnimationTool places video frame at (0, 0). Because scale transform is applied first, we must adjust
    // each translation point by scale factor.
    let translateX = (outputSize.width - newWidth) / 2 / scale
    let translateY = (outputSize.height - newHeight) / 2 / scale

    // Set transform to resize video while retaining aspect ratio
    let resizeTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale, scale)

    // Apply translation & create final transform
    let finalTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(resizeTransform, translateX, translateY)

    // Return final transform
    return finalTransform
}
```

320x568 video taken with Tim's code:

[image]

640x1136 video taken with Tim's code:
[image]

Comment: I'm a little confused about what you're trying to do.  You say live preview, but you seem to have an existing video asset that you're loading?  Are you trying to show the video as you transcode it?

Comment: Users can record video through our app. With this code, we use AVCaptureMovieFileOutput, not AVCaptureVideoDataOutput, to capture the original video. Then the goal is to crop from whatever the preset sessions are to the device dimensions, e.g., 320x568 on a 5S. The output with this approach is not as sharp as the preview layer, so the question is if using AVAssetWriter and AVCaptureVideoDataOutput might fix this (or really, what is the right way to mimic the sharpness of the preview layer). @TimBull Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. Start a new Single View project in Swift, replace the ViewController with this code and you should be good to go!

I've set up a previewLayer which is a different size from the output, change it at the top of the file.

I added some basic orientation support. Outputs slightly different sizes for Landscape Vs. Portrait.  You can specify whatever video size dimensions you like in here and it should work fine.

Checkout the videoSettings dictionary (line 278ish) for the codec and sizes of the output file.  You can also add other settings in here to deal with keyFrameIntervals etc. to tweak outputsize.

I added a recording image to show when it's recording (Tap starts, tap ends), you'll need to add some asset into Assets.xcassets called recording (or comment out that line 106 where it trys to load it).

That's pretty much it. Good luck!

Oh, it's dumping the video into a project directory, you'll need to go to Window / Devices and download the Container to see the video easily.  In the TODO there's a section where you could hook in and copy the file to the PhotoLibrary (makes testing WAY easier).

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate, AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {

let CAPTURE_SIZE_LANDSCAPE: CGSize = CGSizeMake(1280, 720)
let CAPTURE_SIZE_PORTRAIT: CGSize = CGSizeMake(720, 1280)

var recordingImage : UIImageView = UIImageView()

var previewLayer : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?

var audioQueue : dispatch_queue_t?
var videoQueue : dispatch_queue_t?

let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
var assetWriter : AVAssetWriter?
var assetWriterInputCamera : AVAssetWriterInput?
var assetWriterInputAudio : AVAssetWriterInput?
var outputConnection: AVCaptureConnection?

var captureDeviceBack : AVCaptureDevice?
var captureDeviceFront : AVCaptureDevice?
var captureDeviceMic : AVCaptureDevice?
var sessionSetupDone: Bool = false

var isRecordingStarted = false
//var recordingStartedTime = kCMTimeZero
var videoOutputURL : NSURL?

var captureSize: CGSize = CGSizeMake(1280, 720)
var previewFrame: CGRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 180, 360)

var captureDeviceTrigger = true
var captureDevice: AVCaptureDevice? {
    get {
        return captureDeviceTrigger ? captureDeviceFront : captureDeviceBack
    }
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.AllButUpsideDown
}

override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    if isRecordingStarted {
        return false
    }

    if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown {
        return false
    }

    if let cameraPreview = self.previewLayer {
        if let connection = cameraPreview.connection {
            if connection.supportsVideoOrientation {
                switch UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation {
                case .LandscapeLeft:
                    connection.videoOrientation = .LandscapeRight
                case .LandscapeRight:
                    connection.videoOrientation = .LandscapeLeft
                case .Portrait:
                    connection.videoOrientation = .Portrait
                case .FaceUp:
                    return false
                case .FaceDown:
                    return false
                default:
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return true
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupViewControls()

    //self.recordingStartedTime = kCMTimeZero

    // Setup capture session related logic
    videoQueue = dispatch_queue_create("video_write_queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)
    audioQueue = dispatch_queue_create("audio_write_queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)

    setupCaptureDevices()
    pre_start()
}

//MARK: UI methods
func setupViewControls() {

    // TODO: I have an image (red circle) in an Assets.xcassets. Replace the following with your own image
    recordingImage.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
    recordingImage.image = UIImage(named: "recording")
    recordingImage.hidden = true
    self.view.addSubview(recordingImage)


    // Setup tap to record and stop
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "didGetTapped:")
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

}



func didGetTapped(selector: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if self.isRecordingStarted {
        self.view.gestureRecognizers![0].enabled = false
        recordingImage.hidden = true

        self.stopRecording()
    } else {
        recordingImage.hidden = false
        self.startRecording()
    }

    self.isRecordingStarted = !self.isRecordingStarted
}

func switchCamera(selector: UIButton) {
    self.captureDeviceTrigger = !self.captureDeviceTrigger

    pre_start()
}

//MARK: Video logic
func setupCaptureDevices() {
    let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices()

    for device in devices {
        if  device.hasMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) {
            if device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.Front {
                captureDeviceFront = device as? AVCaptureDevice
                NSLog("Video Controller: Setup. Front camera is found")
            }
            if device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.Back {
                captureDeviceBack = device as? AVCaptureDevice
                NSLog("Video Controller: Setup. Back camera is found")
            }
        }

        if device.hasMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio) {
            captureDeviceMic = device as? AVCaptureDevice
            NSLog("Video Controller: Setup. Audio device is found")
        }
    }
}

func alertPermission() {
    let permissionAlert = UIAlertController(title: "No Permission", message: "Please allow access to Camera and Microphone", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    permissionAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Go to settings", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
        print("Video Controller: Permission for camera/mic denied. Going to settings")
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)
        print(UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)
    }))
    presentViewController(permissionAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func pre_start() {
    NSLog("Video Controller: pre_start")
    let videoPermission = AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatusForMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
    let audioPermission = AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatusForMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio)
    if  (videoPermission ==  AVAuthorizationStatus.Denied) || (audioPermission ==  AVAuthorizationStatus.Denied) {
        self.alertPermission()
        pre_start()
        return
    }

    if (videoPermission == AVAuthorizationStatus.Authorized) {
        self.start()
        return
    }

    AVCaptureDevice.requestAccessForMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo, completionHandler: { (granted :Bool) -> Void in
        self.pre_start()
    })
}

func start() {
    NSLog("Video Controller: start")
    if captureSession.running {
        captureSession.beginConfiguration()

        if let currentInput = captureSession.inputs[0] as? AVCaptureInput {
            captureSession.removeInput(currentInput)
        }

        do {
            try captureSession.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice))
        } catch {
            print("Video Controller: begin session. Error adding video input device")
        }

        captureSession.commitConfiguration()
        return
    }

    do {
        try captureSession.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice))
        try captureSession.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDeviceMic))
    } catch {
        print("Video Controller: start. error adding device: \(error)")
    }

    if let layer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession) {
        self.previewLayer = layer
        layer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect

        if let layerConnection = layer.connection {
            if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == .LandscapeRight {
                layerConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.LandscapeLeft
            } else if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == .LandscapeLeft {
                layerConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.LandscapeRight
            } else if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == .Portrait {
                layerConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait
            }
        }

        // TODO: Set the output size of the Preview Layer here
        layer.frame = previewFrame
        self.view.layer.insertSublayer(layer, atIndex: 0)

    }

    let bufferVideoQueue = dispatch_queue_create("sample buffer delegate", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)
    let videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
    videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: bufferVideoQueue)
    captureSession.addOutput(videoOutput)
    if let connection = videoOutput.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) {
        self.outputConnection = connection
    }

    let bufferAudioQueue = dispatch_queue_create("audio buffer delegate", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)
    let audioOutput = AVCaptureAudioDataOutput()
    audioOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: bufferAudioQueue)
    captureSession.addOutput(audioOutput)

    captureSession.startRunning()
}

func getAssetWriter() -> AVAssetWriter? {
    NSLog("Video Controller: getAssetWriter")
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    let urls = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    guard let documentDirectory: NSURL = urls.first else {
        print("Video Controller: getAssetWriter: documentDir Error")
        return nil
    }

    let local_video_name = NSUUID().UUIDString + ".mp4"
    self.videoOutputURL = documentDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent(local_video_name)

    guard let url = self.videoOutputURL else {
        return nil
    }


    self.assetWriter = try? AVAssetWriter(URL: url, fileType: AVFileTypeMPEG4)

    guard let writer = self.assetWriter else {
        return nil
    }

    let videoSettings: [String : AnyObject] = [
        AVVideoCodecKey  : AVVideoCodecH264,
        AVVideoWidthKey  : captureSize.width,
        AVVideoHeightKey : captureSize.height,
    ]

    assetWriterInputCamera = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, outputSettings: videoSettings)
    assetWriterInputCamera?.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true
    writer.addInput(assetWriterInputCamera!)

    let audioSettings : [String : AnyObject] = [
        AVFormatIDKey : NSInteger(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey : 2,
        AVSampleRateKey : NSNumber(double: 44100.0)
    ]

    assetWriterInputAudio = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio, outputSettings: audioSettings)
    assetWriterInputAudio?.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true
    writer.addInput(assetWriterInputAudio!)

    return writer
}

func configurePreset() {
    NSLog("Video Controller: configurePreset")
    if captureSession.canSetSessionPreset(AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720) {
        captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720
    } else {
        captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080
    }
}

func startRecording() {
    NSLog("Video Controller: Start recording")

    captureSize = UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation) ? CAPTURE_SIZE_LANDSCAPE : CAPTURE_SIZE_PORTRAIT

    if let connection = self.outputConnection {

        if connection.supportsVideoOrientation {

            if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == .LandscapeRight {
                connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.LandscapeLeft
                NSLog("orientation: right")
            } else if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == .LandscapeLeft {
                connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.LandscapeRight
                NSLog("orientation: left")
            } else {
                connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait
                NSLog("orientation: portrait")
            }
        }
    }

    if let writer = getAssetWriter() {
        self.assetWriter = writer

        let recordingClock = self.captureSession.masterClock
        writer.startWriting()
        writer.startSessionAtSourceTime(CMClockGetTime(recordingClock))
    }

}

func stopRecording() {
    NSLog("Video Controller: Stop recording")

    if let writer = self.assetWriter {
        writer.finishWritingWithCompletionHandler{Void in
            print("Recording finished")
            // TODO: Handle the video file, copy it from the temp directory etc.
        }
    }
}

//MARK: Implementation for AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate, AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

    if !self.isRecordingStarted {
        return
    }

    if let audio = self.assetWriterInputAudio where connection.audioChannels.count > 0 && audio.readyForMoreMediaData {

        dispatch_async(audioQueue!) {
            audio.appendSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer)
        }
        return
    }

    if let camera = self.assetWriterInputCamera where camera.readyForMoreMediaData {
        dispatch_async(videoQueue!) {
            camera.appendSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer)
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Additional Edit Info**

Its seems from our additional conversations in the comments that what you want is to reduce the physical size of the output video while keeping the dimensions as high as you can (to retain quality).  Remember, the size you position a layer on the screen is POINTs, not PIXELS. You're writing an output file in pixels - it's not a 1:1 comparison to the iPhone screen reference units.

To reduce the size of the output file, you have two easy options:

1. Reduce the resolution - but if you go too small, you'll lose quality when playing it back, especially if when playing it back it gets scaled up again.  Try 640x360 or 720x480 for the output pixels.
2. Adjust the compression settings. The iPhone has default settings that typically produce a higher quality (larger output file size) video.

Replace the video settings with these options and see how you go:

```
    let videoSettings: [String : AnyObject] = [
        AVVideoCodecKey  : AVVideoCodecH264,
        AVVideoWidthKey  : captureSize.width,
        AVVideoHeightKey : captureSize.height,
        AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey : [
            AVVideoAverageBitRateKey : 2000000,
            AVVideoProfileLevelKey : H264_Main_4_1,
            AVVideoMaxKeyFrameIntervalKey : 90,
        ]
    ]
```

The AVCompressionProperties tell AVFoundation how to actually compress the video.  The lower the bit rate, the higher the compression (and therefore the better it streams but ALSO the less disk space it uses BUT it will have lower quality).  MaxKeyFrame interval is how often it writes out an uncompressed frame, setting this higher (in our ~30 frames per second video 90 will be once every 1.5 seconds) also reduces quality but decreases size too.  You'll find the constants referenced here https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundation_Constants/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Video_Settings

Comment: I think this answers your question, if not hopefully it gets you there - essentially what I've tried to demonstrate is a sharp preview and a good output file.  You can make the output file different sizes at the top of the class and see how the effects things.  If you like, just comment out where I resize the preview layer (which was for demo only) and that should get you a full preview - you should be able to resize the video independently without any significant quality impact.

Comment: Whoa, this is awesome! Will try and provide feedback. Thanks so much, Tim!

Comment: And even if it doesn't work, just the suggestion alone to hook into the PhotoLibrary for testing was brilliant! Thanks again, Tim!

Comment: Wow you're amazing. So far, it looks like it works, though will need more testing to confirm. There were several bounties set up for this; wish you could receive credit for all of them instead of a few measly points. One last question: any advice on the right way to overlay an image on the video?

Comment: Hmm, still seeing some issues with clarity. As you can see from the posted images, the sharpness degrades noticeably from 640x1136 as the capture resolution to 320x568 (much easier to notice fuzziness when recording text as opposed to faces). Is it just not possible to mimic the sharpness of the preview because the preview operates at a much higher resolution?

Comment: There's still something I'm not understanding here about why you want to resize the video.  Is it possible you're confusing points with pixels? The reason the iPhone 5 preview is sharp is it's actually 1136x640 pixels (568x320 pts).  When you reduce the pixels (which is what you do when you output at 320x568 pixels when writing the video) you WILL lose quality. http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/sizes.html  More importantly, when you watch that video back, the iPhone is scaling it from 320x568 BACK to 1136x640 pixels (if that's the layer size) which makes the degradation more visible.

Comment: Thanks, Tim. The screenshot was taken by downloading the container and playing on the laptop, but your point makes sense and is what I feared. It just wasn't clear what happened at the preview layer. The reason for resizing to 320x568 is to minimize file size, nothing more. But what it sounds like you're saying is the preview happens at a much higher resolution than 320x568 (which appears to be either 1280x720 or 1920x1080), and there is no magic way to output a 320x568 video that can match the sharpness of the preview layer. Is this correct?

Comment: Check the edits, I've added some detail on ways to reduce the file size of the video while maintaining some quality. Remember that there's always a trade off in terms of File Size Vs. Quality for video.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Tim. You have been incredibly generous. Clarification: the video must be a multiple of the screen size since users can annotate videos with drawings + captions. Anything else distorts the overlay image, and ideally, the video should match the device resolution (e.g., 640x1136 for 5S not 320x568). It seems obvious now, but it was unclear what black magic video gravity did until this weekend. So: (1) other optimizations given this clarification?; (2) to add the overlay, must we add it to every frame, or can we add it to the first frame and have it "repeat" automatically?

Comment: Don't worry about the device resolution, worry about the ratio. It should be 16:9. https://pacoup.com/2011/06/12/list-of-true-169-resolutions/ As for the second question, if you ask that as another question, I can add more detail. Just link it to me in the comments below this one.

Comment: Thanks, Tim. Will read the link. Here's the second q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35420066/how-to-add-static-and-dynamic-overlays-to-video-with-avassetwriter.