# Correctly Record Video Using AVCaptureVideoDataOutput

Tags: swift, delegates, avcapturesession, avcapture, avcapturevideodataoutput

**Background:**

I am using `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` in alignment with `AVCaptureSession` and other various `AV` tools to create a video session such that I can create a camera session. I have a live feed of what the camera sees it is on the screen.

I use `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` and not `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` because the images I obtain through the live feed are processed using `CIFilter`'s. Now, I want to record what is being shown to the user when I press a button. My thoughts on doing this were using the below function as I thought this function captures every frame. I infer this from [Apple's Page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturevideodataoutputsamplebufferdelegate/1385775-captureoutput) which states:

> Delegates receive this message whenever the output captures and outputs a new video frame, decoding or re-encoding it as specified by its videoSettings property. Delegates can use the provided video frame in conjunction with other APIs for further processing.

```
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection)
```

I expected each frame to be here such that I could use an `AVAssetWriter` and add the buffer to the `videoWriterInput`. This can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51209310/save-avcapturevideodataoutput-to-movie-file-using-avassetwriter-in-swift) where the answer indicates that the method `func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection)` adds the `sampleBuffer` to the `videoWriterInput` each time.

**My Efforts:**

I have attempted to simulate the above SO post where the answer utilizes `AVAssetWriter` to write `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` to a file. However, my code, which is indicated below, is not calling the `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate` `func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection)` delegate method.

**NOTE: This is not all the code - I am adding only relevant portions - if there is something missing that you need, please let me know**

**VideoCapture.swift**

```
class VideoCapture: NSObject, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {

    private let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    private let videoDataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
    private let dataOutputQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.Camera.dataOutputQueue")
    private var videoConnection: AVCaptureConnection!

    //NEVER GETS CALLED
    func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        print("Buf: \(sampleBuffer)")
    }

    func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didDrop sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        print("Drop Buff: \(sampleBuffer)")
    }

    init() {
        //Some Setup
        captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.high

        //...
        do {
            // video output
            videoDataOutput.videoSettings = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: Int(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)]
            videoDataOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true
            videoDataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: dataOutputQueue)
            guard captureSession.canAddOutput(videoDataOutput) else { fatalError() }
            captureSession.addOutput(videoDataOutput)
            videoConnection = videoDataOutput.connection(with: .video)
        }
        //...
    }
}
```

**AnotherFile.swift**

```
class VC: UIViewController {

    private var videoCapture: VideoCapture!

    init() {
        self.videoCapture = VideoCapture()
    }

    public override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        guard let videoCapture = videoCapture else {return}
        videoCapture.startCapture()
    }
}
```

**What I Expected:**

I expect the method

```
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection)
```

to be called and at least print out the buffer from the above example. This is not happening, so I am unable to further my development and insert my buffer into a `videoWriteInput` for recording.

**What Actually Happens:**

It is never called. I made sure to setup the delegates using `videoDataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: dataOutputQueue)` and clearly indicate that the delegate methods are made. I was sure to use the auto-complete feature so that the method was created from XCode so I didn't mess up the method name such as [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45628283/captureoutput-function-isnt-called-using-setsamplebufferdelegate).

**Question:**

How can I appropriately get the method to be called -- assuming my intuition is correct that this method is called for each frame and is a buffer I can insert into my `videoWriterInput` -- so that I can record a video from the `AVCaptureSession` I can see on screen?

**Noteworthy:**

[This](https://github.com/shu223/iOS-Depth-Sampler) project ***DOES NOT*** work in terms of calling

```
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection)
```

while [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/60-video-depth-maps-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started) ***DOES*** work.

**EDIT:**

I have found out that for some reason, `AVCaptureDataOutputSynchronizer` causes it to not call the Delegate function. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Alrighty, I have found out the rationale for my torture. So, I was using `AVCaptureMetadataOutput`, `AVCaptureDepthDataOutput`, `AVCaptureAudioDataOutput`, and `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` and combined them using `AVCaptureDataOutputSynchronizer`.

Since I am using `AVCaptureDataOutputSynchronizer`, it is capturing all the delegate calls inside here. For example, I can synchronize my data and it will call the `AVCaptureDataOutputSynchronizer` Delegate method instead of the other individual delegates.

```
dataOutputSynchronizer = AVCaptureDataOutputSynchronizer(dataOutputs: [videoDataOutput, depthDataOutput, metadataOutput])
dataOutputSynchronizer.setDelegate(self, queue: dataOutputQueue)

//... Some Code Later...

func dataOutputSynchronizer(_ synchronizer: AVCaptureDataOutputSynchronizer, didOutput synchronizedDataCollection: AVCaptureSynchronizedDataCollection) {

    guard let syncedVideoData = synchronizedDataCollection.synchronizedData(for: videoDataOutput) as? AVCaptureSynchronizedSampleBufferData else { return }
    guard !syncedVideoData.sampleBufferWasDropped else {
        print("dropped video:\(syncedVideoData)")
        return
    }
    let videoSampleBuffer = syncedVideoData.sampleBuffer
    print(videoSampleBuffer)

    let syncedDepthData = synchronizedDataCollection.synchronizedData(for: depthDataOutput) as? AVCaptureSynchronizedDepthData
    var depthData = syncedDepthData?.depthData
    if let syncedDepthData = syncedDepthData, syncedDepthData.depthDataWasDropped {
        print("dropped depth:\(syncedDepthData)")
        depthData = nil
    }

    // 顔のある位置のしきい値を求める
    let syncedMetaData = synchronizedDataCollection.synchronizedData(for: metadataOutput) as? AVCaptureSynchronizedMetadataObjectData
    var face: AVMetadataObject? = nil
    if let firstFace = syncedMetaData?.metadataObjects.first {
        face = videoDataOutput.transformedMetadataObject(for: firstFace, connection: videoConnection)
    }
    guard let imagePixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(videoSampleBuffer) else { fatalError() }
}
```

This gets called every frame as expected and I can get the individual sets of data, Audio, Video, etc and do what I please with them.

Comment: Did you manage to record audio via `AVCaptureAudioDataOutput`? I see you mentioned it but there is no example in your provided source code.

Comment: I had to record it in it's own object and have its own delegate functions. I can add the source code to this answer for that solution. It might take some time.

Comment: If you find the time please provide some details on that on the example. I'm struggling with recording audio via `dataOutputSynchronizer` callback.

Comment: Yeah - i’d recommend not recording audio with the synchronizer. Put the audio on its own thread